# Type Mismatch: Code worked fine for months and now doesn't

Tags: excel, vba

I've been running this macro for a while now (I use it to hide/unhide rows based on a date in a cell), but all of a sudden it stopped working today; I'm fairly novice at VBA so I've tried looking it up and finding the issue but to no avail... I've made sure all the referenced cells are in the date format but still getting the Type Mismatch error, and it doesn't actually give me the option to debug when the error pops up. (Office Standard Excel 2010)

Any tips would be appreciated!

```
Sub HideRowsDate()
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("B6:B66")
    If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
        If DateValue(Format(cell.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy;@")) > DateValue(Format(Range("AA1"), "dd/mm/yyyy;@")) Then
            'cell = cell.Value
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
    If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
        If DateValue(Format(cell.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy;@")) <= DateValue(Format(Range("AA1"), "dd/mm/yyyy;@")) Then
            'cell = cell.Value
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a thought. You never check to confirm that the data in `Range("AA1")` is actually a date before passing it through to the `DateValue()` function. Is it possible that the value in that column is not a legal date?

Comment: I would advise setting your Range("B6:B66") more explicitly. Like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B6:B66")`. It's hard to know exactly which range your code might by looking at during runtime. The comment above is likely your problem though.

Comment: The way it's written, a type mismatch error could occur at run-time if the `ActiveSheet` isn't what the code assumes it is. Or if `Range("AA1")` doesn't contain an actual date - BTW if the range contains a date, `Range("AA1").Value` *is* a `Date` already. No need to round-trip from date to string to date.

Comment: But Format(Range("AA1"), "dd/mm/yyyy;@") will throw a type mismatch if aa1 is not a valid date and you don't check that it is

Comment: @HarassedDad Don't mind my ignorance, but how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub HideRowsDate()

    Dim cell As Range, dt

    If IsDate(Range("AA1").Value) Then '<< check for date in AA1
        dt = Range("AA1").Value
        For Each cell In Range("B6:B66").Cells
            If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = (cell.Value > dt) 'will be either True or False...
            End If
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "AA1 is not a date!"
    End If

End Sub
```